# javascript regex decode atob

Tags: javascript, regex, string, encoding, base64

I have made a profanity filter in Javascript through regex however I do not wish to have the banned words to show up in my code, so I used the `btoa` to encode the regex; however when I decode it using `atob` the regex does not take any effect. Can any one help???

```
var test = btoa('/poop|smelly/ig');
var decode = atob(test);
alert(decode); // just to show that it works
```

Here is the encode and decode code for the regex. but when I run the regex it does not seem to work???

Comment: a profanity filter isn't a client side job.

Comment: include an example at least

Comment: I know that @CasimiretHippolyte

Comment: I will just do an example one quickly @rock321987, just a minute!

Comment: @rock321987 I have added the code now!!!

Comment: `'/poop|smelly/ig'` is a _String_, not a _RegExp_. You probably wanted to `foo = btoa('poop|smelly')` then `new RegExp(atob(foo), 'ig')`

Answer (score 1):

This will not work, because you have actually turned your regex into a string, which is not the same as a regex literal object.

You could use the `RegExp` constructor to create a regex from a string.

```js
var test = btoa('poop|smelly');
var decode = new RegExp(atob(test), 'ig');
alert(decode.test('smelly'));
alert(decode.test('unfiltered'));
```